# How to put local maven archetype on private server

Tags: git, maven, maven-archetype

I have created an archetype in my system. now i want to put it at some place from where it can be used by everyone in my company. since we are not having any nexus server to deploy it there, so is there any way to put my archetype on central server or git so that everybody can use it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as you not having the private maven repository, so the only way is deliver your archetype as a 3rd jar, then other guys need to install it by the maven command as it must in the user local repository who want to use this jar.

Here is the [Guide to installing 3rd party JARs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)